Azure devops mutil agent parallalsim splits the Nunit test order
The below YML settings splits the ordered Nunit tests between the 2 agensts.
Let's say if MyTestFixture has ordered test cases ([Test, order(1)], [Test, order(2)], [Test, order(3)], [Test, order(4)], [Test, order(5)]) and this test file is last one to run on agent1, then ([Test, order(1)], [Test, order(2)], [Test, order(3)]) are run on agent 1 and other 2 cases on run on agent 2. This fails the 2 test cases on agent2.
How do I prevent this that run ordered tests on same agent keeping the multi agent approah and parallelism still?
   - job: Job_2
      displayName: Integration tests
      timeoutInMinutes: 45
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-2019
      strategy:
        parallel: 2
    .........
    - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'Run Integration Tests'
        inputs:
          testAssemblyVer2: |
            **\bin\**\*.IntegrationTest.dll
          resultsFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/tests-results/
          runInParallel: true
          codeCoverageEnabled: true
          otherConsoleOptions: /platform:X64
          diagnosticsEnabled: true
          collectCoverage: true
          coverageOutputFormat: cobertura
          coverageDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/tests-results/


Hi @Isuru, have you tried to use Category attribute to group the tests and Matrix job strategy to run the pipeline? Do you have any question or need any help?

You can use Category attribute in your tests to group the tests and use testFiltercriteria in VSTest@2 task to filter the tests running in this task. Use Matrix job strategy instead of parallel job strategy to run your jobs in parallel and run the corresponding tests. Refer to the detailed steps below.

Use Category attribute in your tests to group the tests. For example, divide the tests into two groups, which will be run on two agents respectively.

        [Test, Order(1), Category("Group1")]
        [TestCase(0)]
        public void IsPrime_ValuesLessThan2_ReturnFalseTest1(int value)
...
        [Test, Order(4), Category("Group2")]
        [TestCase(3)]
        public void IsPrime_PrimesLessThan10_ReturnTrueTest4(int value)

...


Use Matrix job strategy in your jobs. For each occurrence of string1 in the matrix, a copy of the job is generated. The name string1 is the copy's name and is appended to the name of the job. For each occurrence of string2, a variable called string2 with the value string3 is available to the job.

strategy:
  matrix: { string1: { string2: string3 } }
  maxParallel: number


Use testFiltercriteria in VSTest@2 task to filter the tests will run in this task. For example, testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=$(Category)'.

Example YAML:


jobs:
- job: Test
  displayName: Integration tests
  timeoutInMinutes: 45
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  strategy:
    matrix:
      group1:
        Category: 'Group1'
      group2:
        Category: 'Group2'
    maxParallel: 2
  steps:
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: Run tests in $(Category)
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\bin\**\*test.dll
          **\bin\**\*tests.dll
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        runInParallel: true
        codeCoverageEnabled: true
        testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=$(Category)'


Result: Test case 1-3 run on one agent and test case 4-5 run on another agent. Two jobs run in parallel.


